# How can I check which subcclass the object is in a template?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-templates

Obligatory, I'm a django beginner and I don't understand why my code isn't working.

I'm trying to sort through a parent class in a view to get an object, then pass that object to a template. In the template, I have certain fields showing for each subclass and some which are inherited from the parent class.

I have tried using `isinstance()` in my template but it raised errors. After that I tried to add a static attribute to each subclass to check via an if statement in my template. When doing this, none of the subclass specific fields show. So I tried to set the attribute in the view and still had none of the subclass specific fields display.

Here are the parent object class and one of the subclasses (models):

```
class Chunk(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    images = models.FileField()
    question = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    expected_completion_time = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Concept(Chunk):
    application = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    subconcept1 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    subconcept2 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    subconcept3 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    subconcept4 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    subconcept5 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    subconcept6 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    subconcept7 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    subconcept8 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    subconcept9 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    subconcept10 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    conceptimage = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def mode(self):
        return "concept"
```

Here is the view:

```
def startpomodoro(request):
    key = getpriority(Chunk.objects.all())
    object = Chunk.objects.get(id=key)
    a = random() > 0.5
    mode = str()
    if isinstance(object, Problem):
        if a:
            mode = "problemoutline"
        else:
            mode = "problemfull"
    elif isinstance(object, Concept):
        mode = "concept"
    elif isinstance(object, Formula):
        mode = "formula"
    elif isinstance(object, Code):
        mode = "code"

    context = dict(object=object, mode=mode)
    return render(request, 'pomodoro/pomodorogo.html', context)
```

Here is the relevant part of the template:

```
            <center>

                <p>{{ object.text }}</p>

                {% if mode == concept %}

                    <p>{{ object.application }}</p>

                    <p>{{ object.subconcept1 }}</p>

                    {% if object.subconcept2 %}

                        <p>{{ object.subconcept2 }}</p>

                {% elif mode == formula %}
```

I don't understand why I haven't got any of these methods to work. I'm sure it's an issue in implementation on my part but I don't know what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: But object is not any of those things. It's a Chunk, because that's what you asked for.

Comment: When I create these other things, they are entered in both their respective data tables and the Chunk table. Are you saying that what I've done only allows me to access the information available in the Chunk table? If so, could you recommend any appropriate methods to go from the Chunk to its respective subclass data?

Comment: The simplest solution I see is using OneToOneField for inheritance.
So check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

Comment: Can you confirm that `{{ mode }}` and `{{ object }}` are printing the expected result in the template?

Comment: @Asher When I print {{ object }} I get the object name (I think due to the __str__() ) but there is no output for mode. This would seem to agree with Daniel that the object selected is only the parent class version.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you, I've made that modification.

Comment: @EvgenyKuzmovich wouldn't that make it difficult to create objects of the subclass? As in I would have to make the parent class object then create the subclass object with all inherited fields being the same. If I did this, sure I would want to extend the parent object with other classes using the one-to-one rather than inheriting.

Comment: @Era I am not sure if I understood you correct. Yes, you would need to create parent class object at first and then pass it as a parameter to subclass object. So it would look like that: 
`chunk = Chunk.objects.create(**chunk_data)
concept = Concept.objects.create(**concept_data, chunk=chunk)`

Comment: @EvgenyKuzmovich A subclass automatically has a OneToOneField to its superclass [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance] (Django MTI Docs) but your suggestion is helpful. I think I now need to use try/except with this relationship until I get the correct subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have some unnecessary complications in your models, try a simplified model:

```
class SubConcept(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Chunk(models.Model):

    CHUNK_TYPES = [('P', 'Problem'),
                   ('C', 'Concept'),
                   ('I', 'Idea'),
                   ('K', 'Code'),
                   ('F', 'Formula')]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    image = models.FileField()
    question = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    expected_completion_time = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    chunk_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHUNK_TYPES)
    application = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subs = models.ManyToManyField(SubConcept, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name or '')

    @property
    def mode(self):
       return dict(CHUNK_TYPES)[self.chunk_type]
```

Now, your view is quite simple (I'm ignoring the `getpriority` method because I have no idea what it does):

```
def pomodoro(request):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Chunk, pk=1)
    return render(request, 'foo.html', {'obj': obj})
```

Here is your template:

```
<center>
 <p>{{ obj.text }}</p>
 {% if obj.mode == 'Concept' %}
    <p>{{ object.application }}</p>
    {% for sub in obj.subs.all %}
        <p>{{ sub.name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
 {% elif obj.mode == 'Formula' %}
    ...
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

On one Django project I was working on we had a similar issue to this with inherited model classes. The solution we used was to add a type to the parent class.

```
class Chunk(models.Model):
    CONCEPT_TYPES = (
        ('Problem', 'Problem'),
        ('Concept', 'Concept'),
        ('Formula', 'Formula'),
        ('Code', 'Code'),
    )
    concept_type = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=CONCEPT_TYPES)
    ...
```

Then in our templates we would do something like:

```
{% if object.concept_type == 'Concept' %}
   <p>{{ object.concept.application }}</p>
   <p>{{ object.concept.subconcept1 }}</p>
{% elif object.type == 'Problem' %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Things to note are that in the future I wouldn't structure my database like this again unless there was a very compelling reason and there are almost certainly better solutions.

You should also try changing your if statement in views.py to something like:

```
if object.problem:
    ...
elif object.concept:
    ....
```

This might mean that you don't need to put a type row in your models.